# magmi do not import first media_gallery image

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm using magmi 0.7.22 in a magento 1.9.3.1

I need to import several images, and replace all the current images by the new ones.

I'm trying first with on single product and I see that it is working fine, except that the first media_gallery image is not imported.

The test csv is the following:

```
"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail","media_gallery"
"S1712400-10","+/S1712400-5-10.jpg","+/S1712400-5-10.jpg","+/S1712400-5-10.jpg","/S1712400-2-10.jpg;/S1712400-3-10.jpg;/S1712400-4-10.jpg"
```

The import finishes without any error, but the image `S1712400-5-10.jpg` is not showing anywhere, though the other 2 following images are in it's place.

I checked that the image name is correct, and that it is in the same place as the other ones, but still the same result.

I cleared all the magento's caches, including the "catalog images cache" but see no change.

The same happens to all the products, the first image of the media_gallery is completely ignored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I see several related questions about magmi in stackoverflow and none of them are closed.

Comment: But they should be. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. The site help specifically says that a question must be about "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Your question is not "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71962/import-multiple-images-with-magmi

It seems there is some problem with `Image attributes processor v1.0.33a` image renaming.

To solve this go to `itemprocessors` and in the `Image attributes processor v1.0.33a` select configuration. Then empty the `Image renaming` and save.

This solved my problem.